# Issue - Integrating angualrjs with socket.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` and `angularjs` for showing the real time data in my project.

`socket.io` is working fine  without **angularjs**.

#### controller.js

```
   var realTime = angular.module('realTime',[]);
   realTime.controller('realTime', function($scope) { });
   realTime.factory('socket', function($rootScope) { });

   realTime.controller('realTime', function($scope,socket) {
    //socket is undefined
      socket.on('realTimeData', function (result) {
          $scope.realTimeCount = 2;
      });

    });
```

Above code is in the controller.js, Socket.io is emitting the `realTimeData` event data to client side at regular interval.  Problem is in client side.

#### Problem

```
socket is undefined inside the `realTime.controller` function.
```

**Note:**  Added the socket.io script in html file

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Any help or suggestion will be greatful.

Comment: where you have defined io.connect ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your `socket` factory resource (`realTime.factory('socket', function($rootScope) { });`) you leave it empty. Your socket methods (on, emit etc.) should be in there for it to work properly.

So try this instead:

```
realTime.factory('socket', function($rootScope) {   
  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

It's explained in great detail [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/).